# How do you join two tables on a foreign key field using django ORM?

Tags: python, database, django, postgresql, orm

Let's assume I have the following models:

```
class Position(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class PositionStats(models.Model):
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)
    averageYards = models.CharField()
    averageCatches = models.CharField()

class PlayerStats(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    averageYards = models.CharField()
    averageCatches = models.CharField()

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)
```

I want to perform the equivalent SQL query using django's ORM:

```
SELECT *

FROM PlayerStats

JOIN Player ON player

JOIN PositionStats ON PositionStats.position = Player.position
```

How would I do that with django's ORM? The query isn't exactly correct, but the idea is that I want a single query, using django's ORM, that gives me `PlayerStats` joined with `PositionStats` based on the player's position.

Comment: All the answers are for 2 table join where question was to join 3 tables with just Django ORM.

Answer (score 41):

I've been working with django for a while now and I have had a pretty rough time figuring out the table joins, but I think I finally understand and I would like to pass this on to others so they may avoid the frustration that I had with it.

Consider the following model.py:

```
class EventsMeetinglocation(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'events_meetinglocation'

class EventsBoardmeeting(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    agenda_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    location_id = models.ForeignKey(EventsMeetinglocation)
    minutes_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
       managed = True
       db_table = 'events_boardmeeting'
```

Here we can see that `location_id` in `EventsBoardmeeting` is a foreign key for the id in `EventsMeetinglocation`. This means that we should be able to query the information in `EventsMeetinglocation` by going through `EventsBoardmeeting`.

Now consider the following views.py:

```
def meetings(request):
    meetingData = EventsBoardmeeting.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'board/meetings.html', {'data': meetingData })
```

As stated many times before in may other posts, django takes care of joins automatically. When we query everything in `EventsBoardmeeting` we also get any related information by foreign key as well, But the way that we access this in html is a little different. We have to go through the variable used as the foreign key to access the information associated with that join. For example:

```
{% for x in data %}
   {{ x.location_id.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

The above references ALL of the names in the table that were the result of the join on foreign key. `x` is essentially the `EventsBoardmeeting` table, so when we access `x.location_id` we are accessing the foreign key which gives us access to the information in `EventsMeetinglocation`.

Comment: I can't describe to you how amazingly helpful this post was. I've been searching the internet for almost a week trying to figure out how to call variables from the joined dataset in html. I could see the data I wanted in my queryset if I printed it but I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to get it to display in page. 

THANK YOU!

Comment: what are the functions of the following codes in your answer @conna stone
class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'events_meetinglocation'  and

class Meta:
       managed = True
       db_table = 'events_boardmeeting'

Comment: In an SQL DB, when you do a join (as described by OP), you get (or can get) 1 big table whose columns are fields from both tables in the join, and in my ancient perl experience, you could just make 1 loop and render that 1 big table. Here it seems that if I want that 1 big table in a template, I'd have to do a series of nested loops to reproduce such a denormalized table (where records from either table may be repeated depending on the relationships). Someone told me in django you don't have to do nested loops, but I cannot find out how. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you extend this if there are 3 tables involved who have many to many relationship ?

Answer (score 17):

`select_related()` and `prefetch_related()` is your solution. They work almost same way but has some difference.

`select_related()` works by creating an SQL join and including the fields of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason, `select_related` gets the related objects in the same database query. But it only works for one-to-one or one-to-many relation. Example is below-

```
entry = Entry.objects.select_related('blog').get(id=5)
or
entries = Entry.objects.filter(foo='bar').select_related('blog')
```

`prefetch_related()`, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using `select_related`. So `prefetch_related` will execute only one query for each relation. Example is given below-

```
Pizza.objects.all().prefetch_related('toppings')
```

Comment: Thanks! For the details, I've found this amazing article: https://medium.com/better-programming/django-select-related-and-prefetch-related-f23043fd635d

Answer (score 13):

It isn't one query, but it's pretty efficient. This does one query for each table involved, and joins them in Python.  More on `prefetch_related` here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

```
Player.objects.filter(name="Bob").prefetch_related(
        'position__positionstats_set', 'playerstats_set')
```

Answer (score 3):

In Django 3.2, the framework automatically follows relationships when using method QuerySet.filter()

```
# The API automatically follows relationships as far as you need.
# Use double underscores to separate relationships.
# This works as many levels deep as you want; there's no limit.
# Find all Choices for any question whose pub_date is in this year
# (reusing the 'current_year' variable we created above).
>>> Choice.objects.filter(question__pub_date__year=current_year)
```

This compiles to the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    "polls_choice"."id",
    "polls_choice"."question_id",
    "polls_choice"."choice_text",
    "polls_choice"."votes"
FROM
    "polls_choice"
INNER JOIN "polls_question" ON
    ("polls_choice"."question_id" = "polls_question"."id")
WHERE
    "polls_question"."pub_date" BETWEEN 2020-12-31 23:00:00 AND 2021-12-31 22:59:59.999999
```

See tutorial here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/

Answer (score -6):

From `django.db` import connection In your view include the below statement:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * From Postion ON Position.name = Player.position JOIN
PlayerStats ON Player.name = 
PlayerStats.player JOIN PositionStats ON Position.name = PositionStats.player")
solution = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: OP specifically mentions "I want to perform the equivalent SQL query using django's ORM". This answer gives the raw SQL way of doing it, without using the ORM.

Comment: Yes please read the actual question. Correct what @NishantGeorgeAgrwal said.