# django- Use prefetch_related inside of another prefetch_related

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

Closest thing to what I am asking can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092268/how-do-you-join-two-tables-on-a-foreign-key-field-using-django-orm)

Say I have the following models:

```
class Division(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    state = models.IntegerField()

class Team(models.Model):
    name2 = models.TextField()
    division = models.ForeignKey(Division, ...)

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    hometown = models.IntegerField()
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, ...)
```

Now I can already do the following for just one table:

```
players = Player.objects.prefetch_related('team')
```

How would I go about adding `state` to the queryset? My endgoal is to be able to do `player.team.division.state` inside of a template. The other alternative would be to use nested for loops but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Your example models are difficult to understand because they have very similar names and fields. There is no foreign key/many-to-many field from another model to `model3`, so there is no reason to use `prefetch_related` here. A simple `select_related` would work.

Comment: @Alasdair Please have a look at my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `prefetch_related` here. You can follow the foreign keys from `Player` to `Team` to `Division` using [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

```
players = Player.objects.select_related('team__division')
```

A use-case for `prefetch_related` is if you started with a `Division` queryset, and wanted to fetch the related teams at the same time.

Comment: Not sure if this should be a different question but: how would I get team and players in 1 queryset even if a team had no player?

Comment: That's a separate question. Before you ask a new question, look at the [prefetch related docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). The example models are pretty similar to yours. You can use prefetch related for your reverse foreign key from team to player, in the same way that they use it for many-to-many fields.

Comment: I found the [prefetch objects documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) to be extremely useful as well.