# Django - Select related or join on two different base models

Tags: python, django

I have two base models SiteData and Showoroom Service that have model structure as per the below.

I need the SiteData info but I also would like to get link_type from the showroomservice model if there is a matching ID.

ive tried a few things thus far, none are getting what I need, what is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

select related

```
>>> nd = ShowroomService.objects.select_related('site').all()
>>> nd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 229, in __repr__
    return '<%s %r>' % (self.__class__.__name__, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 590, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type SiteData)
```

Combining :

```
>>> complete_data = site_data | monitoring_data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 310, in __or__
    combined.query.combine(other.query, sql.OR)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 529, in combine
    "Cannot combine queries on two different base models."
AssertionError: Cannot combine queries on two different base models.
```

chaining

```
>>> final_data = chain(monitoring_data, site_data)
>>> for i in final_data:
...  '{} {}'.format(i.location,i.link_Type)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ShowroomService' object has no attribute 'location'
```

sites.models.py

```
class SiteData(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    site_type = models.ForeignKey(SiteTypes, verbose_name="Site Type", \
                on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    subnet = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4')
    routed_subnet = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', \
                    verbose_name="Routed Link Subnet", blank=True, null=True)
    bgp_as = models.CharField(max_length=6, verbose_name="BGP AS Number")
    opening_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Showroom opening date")
    last_hw_refresh_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date of latest hardware refresh", \
                           blank=True, null=True)
    is_live = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Is this a live site?")
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Site Data"
        verbose_name_plural = "Site Data"
        ordering = ('location',)
        permissions = (
            ("can_view", "Can View"),
            ("can_view_mgmt", "Can View Management"),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location
```

monitoring.models.py

```
from sites.models import SiteData

class ShowroomService(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(SiteData, verbose_name="Site", \
        on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    link_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    preference = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    dashboard = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="display on monitoring dashboard?")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Showroom Service Data"
        verbose_name_plural = "Showroom Service Data"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.site
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the question right, you have a list of SiteData models and you'd like to follow the foreign key backwards and get all child ShowroomService records?

Comment: Your first error has nothing to do with your question, but as the message states is because you are returning a Site object rather than a string from the `__str__` method.

Comment: yeah, in a template I want to display all the site data info plus the link type from showroomservice. when I use a set in the template, looking at debug toolbar I am running 90+ queries because of the set command so I want to combine them before sending them to the template to save the queries

Comment: So you're trying to avoid using the `*_set` attribute like I posted in my answer?

Comment: yes, the set is running 90+ queries (one for each site) which seems very inefficient, I thought if I get the two tables I could join them on site.id and do it in two instead of 90

Comment: That's sort of one of the pitfalls of using an ORM to be honest. Nicer to use/nicer looking code could equal a ton of queries/bad performance. I'll see what I can do and post an edit to my answer if I can come up with something.

Comment: Posted an edit with a link to prefetch_related. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull all related objects using django's "related manager". Documentation is available here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference

By calling `showroom_service_set` on a `SiteData` model, you can get the set of child records for each `SiteData`.

Just to explain why the listed attempts failed as well:

1. your `__str__` methods on your models *need* to return strings. If they don't, you'll get that exception.
2. The pipe operator `|` is used for `OR`ing together queries in django. That chunk of code is attempting to combine a query for 2 different types of models.
3. With the chain attempt, you've created a list containing two different types of models. One of which doesn't have a `location` attribute.

Here's a chunk of code to get the link type for all ShowroomService models attached to a SiteData model:

```
for site_data in SiteData.objects.all():
    for showroom in site_data.showroom_service_set.all():
        print showroom.link_type
```

I'm not sure how django handles camel-casing with related objects, so `showroom_service_set` is my best guess. You might have to do a little leg work on this to figure out what the actual set is called.

EDIT: There's something called prefetch_related. Here's a SO answer about it; I think it'll get you what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13096423/769971

Comment: prefetch related does it, 6 queries in 29ms in stead of 100 in 150ms now :)