# How to Join two tables in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

```
select *
from article_article
left join article_upvote ON article_article.id=article_upvote.article_id
```

I want to write this query with Django ORM. How can I write this? Please help

Comment: How can we help you when you haven't even posted your models?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you join two tables on a foreign key field using django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092268/how-do-you-join-two-tables-on-a-foreign-key-field-using-django-orm)

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49357908/3708462

Answer (score 2):

You can use prefetch related:

```
articles = Article.objects.all().prefetch_related('upvote')
```

If you want to see the query executed do:

```
print(articles.query)
```