# how can i filter the objects of a model if only the field of another model contains a certain value and these two models have foreign keys

Tags: django, view, model, querying

I have two models: Model Order

```
class Order(models.Model):
    truck = models.ForeignKey(Truck, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='relation_truck',default=None)
    date= models.DateField()
    product=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    depot = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    volume = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    volume_delivered = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

and another model which is Model Loaded:

```
class Loaded(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='relation_order',default=None)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

I want to filer the objects with `order_status=Released` and `Loaded` from model `Order` on my model `Loaded` in the views because I have the foreign key order.

in my views I have something like:

```
def loading(request):
    loaded =   Loaded.objects.filter(order__order_status__in=['Loaded', 'Released'])
    return render(request, 'loadings.html' , {'loaded':loaded})
```

and in my html:

```
                                        <table id="datatable2" class="table order-column hover">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Truck NO.</th>
                                                    <th>Date</th>
                                                    <th>Product</th>
                                                    <th>Volume</th>
                                                    <th>Volume @20</th>
                                                    <th>Depot</th>
                                                    <th>Driver</th>
                                                    <th>Driver Tel</th>
                                                    <th>Driver ID</th>
                                                    <th>Status</th>

                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                {% for car in loaded %}
                                                  <tr class="gradeX">
                                                  <td>{{car.order.truck.truck_number}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{car.order.date}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{car.order.product}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{car.order.volume}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{car.order.volume_delivered}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{car.order.depot}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{car.order.truck.driver_name}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{car.order.truck.driver_phone_number}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{car.order.truck.driver_id_number}}</td>
                                                  <td><input type="checkbox" id="toggle-two"></td>


                                                    </tr>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

what i want is the orders with order_status Loaded and Received only to show in my loadings.html

Comment: Hey @MANKA MEHDI,
you can use something like: `Loaded.objects.filter(order__order_status='Loaded')`

Comment: Please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092268/how-do-you-join-two-tables-on-a-foreign-key-field-using-django-orm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you join two tables on a foreign key field using django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092268/how-do-you-join-two-tables-on-a-foreign-key-field-using-django-orm)

Comment: @PhilippZettl it didnt work

Comment: @theBuzzyCoder can you please help me on how to use the prefetch_related and select_related somehow i got confused and they are giving me errors

Comment: @MANKAMEHDI Please take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships. Don't think in terms of which function to use `prefetch_related` or `select_related`. What you need here is an SQL join table query. You need to figure out how to achieve that in Django. The given link will help you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
loaded_or_released = Loaded.objects.filter(Q(order__order_status='Loaded') | Q(order__order_status='Released') )[0:200]
```

Answer (score 0):

First let me explain the problem so that I can make sure that I have understood the problem correctly!

- Order has foreign Truck
- Loaded has foreign Order

which means `1` order can have `n` loaded items.

You want all the loaded items having order_status in `Loaded` or `Released`.

[Django one-to-many relationship lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#one-to-many-relationships)

If this is what you want to achieve, then

```
all_loaded_items = Loaded.objects.filter(order__order_status__in=['Loaded', 'Released'])
```

in the filter arguments after splitting argument name by `__`

- `order` is the foreign field
- `order_status` is field in foreign field
- `in` is the operator like mysql's in operator

Where all_loaded_items is of type QuerySet.

Comment: can you please review the question i have edited it and explained it further.

Comment: put the line`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` after `def loading(request):` in views.py. Then do `python manage.py runserver` in terminal and load the page. Come back to  the terminal and the manage.py will show a prompt `(pdb)`. There type `n` and enter. Then it will execute your next line and give prompt back. Then, type `print(loaded)` and see what is the result. That's how you debug.

Comment: the queryset is empty i am getting                                                                          :  (Pdb) print(loaded)
(Pdb) <QuerySet []>

Comment: So, there's your answer. First see if you've data in your tables. Assuming you're using SQL/MySQL/Mariadb, run this `select * from order as o join loaded as l on l.order_id=o.id where o.order_status in ('Released', 'Loaded');`. See if you get output. Also to know what are you're table names use `show tables;` in mysql/mariadb.