# django subquery without using group by

Tags: python, django, orm, model

```
 class Config(models.Model):
     id = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
     appid = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
     status = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
     user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
     name = models.IntegerField(max_length=10,null=False,default='0')
     path = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,default='')
     create_time =  models.DateTimeField()

class User(models.Model):
     hostip = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
```

I need to know how to write a django subquery.

I need equal django query for below MySQL query.

```
select *  from ((select A.appid,User.hostip ,A.name,A.path,A.status,A.create_time from Config as A left join  User on  A.appid = 1255 and User.hostip= '172.16.0.3') as B ) group by B.name order by B.create_time;
```

Kindly let me know..................

Comment: In Django you have to think in models, not in SQL. Please explain in words what you are trying to archive!

Answer (score 1):

My solution：Django get all values Group By particular one field

```
queryset = Config.objects.filter(appid=appid,user_id__hostip=hostip,path__isnull=False)

queryset = queryset.all()

queryset.query.group_by = ['name']

queryset = queryset.order_by('create_time')
```

Then I  get all objects by group by only 1 column

Answer (score 0):

[this link may help to create a join clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092268/how-do-you-join-two-tables-on-a-foreign-key-field-using-django-orm)
if t maybe not necessary to use join, because django syntax allow to rich related objects by using dot notation or by using double underscores.
and for the part you want to limit fields of table, you may have a look at [Values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)
or in that link comes later [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)