# Django inner join methods return unexpected results

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, geodjango

I am new to Django's ORM and am confused by inner join conventions despite having consulted the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092268/how-do-you-join-two-tables-on-a-foreign-key-field-using-django-orm) on SO.  I have two tables - `MyPoints` and `MyBuffers` that are one-to-one related by `projectid` (no duplicates in either table). My goal is to fetch the `radius` field using inner join on `projectid`.  Even though I have defined a foreign key, my first attempt at fetching all of the fields from `MyBuffers` returns nothing from the joined table, and my second attempt at fetching one field from `MyBuffers` errors.  What is wrong with the syntax or methodology here?  Should key columns be named differently?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

*models.py*

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class MyBuffers(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    projectid = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    radius = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'my_buffers'

class MyPoints(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    projectid = models.ForeignKey('MyBuffers', max_length=25, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, to_field='projectid', db_column='projectid')
    geog = models.PointField(geography=True, srid=4326) 

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'my_points'
```

*views.py*

```
from .models import MyPoints
from .models import MyBuffers
```

1.Does not return any fields in from the joined `MyBuffers` table

```
test = MyPoints.objects.select_related('projectid')
test.first().__dict__

{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7f3e21786520>, 'id': 5808, 'projectid_id': 'foobar1', 'geog': <Point object at 0x7f3e21738910>}
```

2.Throws an errors

```
test= MyPoints.objects.select_related('projectid__radius')
test.first().__dict__
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Non-relational field given in select_related: 'radius'. Choices are: (none)
```

Comment: You can access the fields `MyBuffers` like: `test.first().projectid.radius`. You just don't see `projectid` in the `__dict__`.

Comment: For the 2nd error, `select_related` and `prefetch_related` only works on relational fields (as the error says) so it's intended for foreign key fields. You don't have to specify `__radius` because it's already fetched by `select_related('projectid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think select related only works in foreign keys. So if you are trying to get fields other than foreign keys it will throw an error. Your queryset must be

```
test= MyPoints.objects.select_related('projectid')
# To get radius
test.first().projectid.radius
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class MyBuffers(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    projectid = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    radius = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'my_buffers'

class MyPoints(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    projectid = models.ForeignKey('MyBuffers', 
    max_length=25,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    geog = models.PointField(geography=True, srid=4326) 
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'my_points'
```

**Try the following code**