# How to use this SQL statement in Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, database, django-models, django-orm

Please help me with converting this SQL statament in Django ORM

```
SELECT postupci.Postupak ,SUM(unosi.Komada), unosi.Radnik" \
                    " FROM unosi INNER JOIN postupci ON unosi.Operacija = postupci.Id" \
                    " AND unosi.Datum >= 2022-11-01 AND unosi.Datum < 2022-12-10 \
                    " GROUP BY postupci.Postupak"
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant models and what you have tried so far to your question?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092268/how-do-you-join-two-tables-on-a-foreign-key-field-using-django-orm?